# WNetCancelConnection returning Error 2250 :This network connection does not exist in Windows Service

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services

WNetCancelConnection returning Error 2250 : This network connection does not exist in Windows Service written in VC++

Same Code works fine in a MFC Application.

My code looks like :

```
DWORD dwretVal = 0;
dwRetVal =  WNetCancelConnectionW(wcpDrive,FALSE);
```

Here wcpDrive = X:

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive letter mappings are tied to individual user accounts.  The service is likely running in a user account (usually the SYSTEM account, unless configured otherwise) that does not have the X drive letter mapped to anything.  If you need to unmap a drive letter that belongs to another user account, your service will need to impersonate that user first.

Comment: I am impersonating that user in service by clicking on Logon and providing administator a/c details but it is not working it seems

Comment: @Swapnil: Does the admin account you are using actually have an X: drive letter mapped?  Are you sure your service is running in the same user account that your MFC app is running in?  Have you tried impersonating the user account in code and then loading its profile via `LoadUserProfile()` so the drive mappings are loaded?